# Jackson Object Mapper convert JsonArray to JsonString

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to transform the below `JsonArray` with timestamp , x and y fields

```
[
  1588464000,
  1,
  0
],
[
  1589068800,
  0,
  0
]
]
```

To JsonString

```
[ {
    "timestamp": "1367712000",
     "x": 6898,
      "y": 18728,
   }
]

String jsonString2 = mapper.writer().writeValueAsString(response);
```

and I get below response and I get the following response

```
{
 "headers": {
  "Strict-Transport-Security": [
   ],
 "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": [
   ],
 "Status": ["200 OK"],
 "Content-Length": ["3105"],
 "Server": ["x.com"],
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": [ "*"]
 },
 "body": "[[1588464000,1,0],[1589068800,1,0],",
 "statusCode": "OK",
 "statusCodeValue": 200
}
```

not sure how to get the right response for the jsonArray, with the just body to be part of the response. Wonder I am getting the headers information, status code, statusValue in the response

PayLoadDto

```
public class PayLoadDto {
        private int x;
        private int y;
        @JsonValue
        private String json;
        private String timestamp;
        public PayLoadDto(int x, int y, String json, String timestamp) {
            this.x = x;
            this.x = x;
            this.json = json;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        } public PayLoadDto(String json) {
            this.json = json;
        } 
    public int getX(){
            return x;
        }
     public int getY(){
            return y;
        } 
    public String getJson(){
            return json;
        } 
    public String getTimestamp(){
            return timestamp;
        }


ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange( url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class ); 
PayLoadDto PayLoadDto = new PayLoadDto(response.toString()); 
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(PayLoadDto);
```

Comment: What is the `response` variable type? How are you generating it? Please update the question with code.

Comment: I am making a call to server and transform the api response  to transform to a json string using spring boot controller                                                 ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            url,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            request,
            String.class
    );                                                                                                        
     PayLoadDto PayLoadDto = new PayLoadDto(response.toString());
       jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(PayLoadDto);

Comment: Please [edit] and update the code in question instead of comments. Also, share the code of `PayLoadDto`.

Comment: How would you figure out which field is `x` and `y` if the response doesn't have those fields when you get it from the server?

Answer (score 0):

As per comments of OP, data will always be in sequence of `timestamp`, `x`, `y`. So, we can read the json body as `List<List<String>>` and then set the valus to `PayloadDto` object.

```java
// Fetch data from API
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange( url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class );

// Read body from response
String jsonBody = response.getBody();

// Read jsonBody as List
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<List<String>> dataList = mapper.readValue(jsonBody, new TypeReference<List<List<String>>>(){});

// Convert List to POJO List
List<PayLoadDto> payLoadDtos = new ArrayList<>();
dataList.forEach(item -> {
    PayLoadDto payLoadDto = new PayLoadDto();
    payLoadDto.setTimestamp(item.get(0));
    payLoadDto.setX(Integer.parseInt(item.get(1)));
    payLoadDto.setY(Integer.parseInt(item.get(2)));
    payLoadDtos.add(payLoadDto);
});

// Convert POJOs to JSON String
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(payLoadDtos));
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 0,
    "timestamp": "1588464000"
  },
  {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 0,
    "timestamp": "1589068800"
  }
]
```

Comment: This might not work by default if the response from the server doesn't have the fields of PayLoadDto as jackson won't be able to deserialize it to the PayLoadDto fields

Comment: the response from the server does not have fields that of PayLoadDto, is there a way to map response to fields?

Comment: @MadhuBhat yes of-course, that's why I have commented to ask for `PayLoadDto`'s structure.

Comment: @user0007 Please [edit] and update question with `PayLoadDto`

Comment: added the payLoadDto structure

Comment: @user0007 How will you identify the mapping between response and `PayloadDto` attributes? Will the response always be in sequence like `[1588464000,1,0]` always mapping to `timestamp`, `x`, `y` in sequence?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214194/discussion-between-user0007-and-smile).